# Default directory permissions over NFS

Tags: permissions, nfs

I have two servers, `client` and `server` in fairly obvious roles: `server` hosts the NFS share and `client` has it mounted. There is a shared group among several users on `client` called `shared` which also exists on `server`. My permissions on `server` for the share look like this:

```
user@server $ ls -al /export/share/
drwxrwsr-x+ 3 shared shared    4096 Apr 19 01:25 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root       4096 Apr 12 20:10 ..
```

The goal is pretty clearly displayed, I'd like all members of the `shared` group to be able to create, write, and delete files in this directory. On client, a `ls -la` of the mounted directory leads the same results.

The NFS exports file on `server` looks like this:

```
/export/share 10.0.0.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

The mount on `client` in `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
10.0.0.1:/export/share /mnt/share nfs _netdev,noatime,intr,auto 0 0
```

The output of `mount` from `client`:

```
10.0.0.1:/export/share on /mnt/streams type nfs (rw,noatime,intr,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.1,clientaddr=10.0.0.2)
```

However, I still can't seem to be able to create files in that directory using a user in the group.

For instance, a user `jack`:

```
user@server $ id jack
uid=1001(jack) gid=1001(jack) groups=1001(jack),1010(shared)
```

If I try touching a file in the mounted folder on `client`, permission is denied:

```
user@client $ sudo -u jack touch /mnt/share/a
touch: cannot touch `/mnt/share/a': Permission denied
```

Why isn't this working as expected? Shouldn't I be able to create files and folders as `jack` in this folder since he's a member of the `shared` group?

Comment: Just a guess but it might have something to do with "other" having read-only permissions and that the user on `client` is probably using the `nobody` user account. I would give the writable bit to world, touch a new file, and see who ends up owning that file.

Comment: Make sure the NFS is exported RW, also check the group id on the nfs server and client to make sure shared is the same gid

Comment: Can you provide the output from the command `mount`? Also can root on the client create a file on the mount?

Comment: I've provided the output in the answer and it seems that even `root` can't create a file there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you disseminating the user/group info that's contained in `/etc/passwd` and /etc/group? You typically need to use NIS, LDAP, or rsync the `/etc/passwd` `/etc/group` files to all the machines that are automounting these mounts. Otherwise the clients know nothing of the permissions on the filesystem.

You might want to peruse the [NIS Howto](http://www.linux-nis.org/nis-howto/HOWTO/settingup_client.html).

Comment: User `jake` doesn't exist on `server` but he does on `client`. Could that be the problem? The group exists with the same id on both `client` and `server`.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, the userid's need to match on the client and the filesystem being exported from the server. It doesn't key off of the name it's the userid's in the /etc/passwd file that are key. These are what's written to the disk.

Comment: Ultimate solution: You basically need a perfect copy of the users, groups, and their relationships (which users belong to which groups) on `server`.

Answer (score 1):

NFS works with "groupid" and "userid", the actual numbers not the names.
Make sure that groups and users have the same id on both server and client.
Check `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` on both server and client.
An ideal setup is to have all users and groups shared over NIS or LDAP server.